# Unit Testing controller in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to do a unit test on the list action of a controller. Here is the code for testing it :

```
  void testListAction()
   {
       ac = new AddressesController();

       def org = new Organizations(viewAllPost: true);
       mockForConstraintsTests(Addresses);
       def a = new Addresses(firstLine:'A', secondLine:'B', thirdLine:'C', luCountry:UnitedStates, zipCode:'12345', luState:Florida, city:'jag');
       assertTrue(a.validate());
       mockSession['currentUserOrganizationId'] = org;  

       mockDomain(Addresses, [
           new Addresses(firstLine:'A1', secondLine:'B', thirdLine:'C', luCountry:UnitedStates, zipCode:'12345', luState:Florida, city:'jag'),
           new Addresses(firstLine:'A2', secondLine:'B2', thirdLine:'C2', luCountry:UnitedStates, zipCode:'12344', luState:Florida, city:'jag2')
           ]);

        def model = ac.list();
       assertEquals(2, model.postInstanceList.size());
   }
```

But No matter how I tried I am always getting back the same result that the model.postInstanceList is null and I can not invoke the size method on it. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Some pointers - you shouldn't need to create an instance of the controller.  Assuming your test class is called AddressControllerTests, an instance of AddressController should already be available via the variable 'controller'.  Also, I wouldn't test the size of the model, I'd test the response; controller.response.???.  Testing controllers, you want to test the response you get back.

Comment: These are both correct pointers. I need to test the actual contents in the list, but first of all I was just testing if the list got correct size or not, which should be easier test And even this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the instances. You should save:

```
mockDomain(Addresses)
new Addresses(firstLine:'A1', secondLine:'B', thirdLine:'C', luCountry:UnitedStates, zipCode:'12345', luState:Florida, city:'jag').save()

new Addresses(firstLine:'A2', secondLine:'B2', thirdLine:'C2', luCountry:UnitedStates, zipCode:'12344', luState:Florida, city:'jag2').save()
```

I would do it like this:

```
mockDomain(Addresses)
mockForContraintsTests(Addresses)
def address1 = new Addresses(firstLine:'A1', secondLine:'B', thirdLine:'C', luCountry:UnitedStates, zipCode:'12345', luState:Florida, city:'jag')
if(address1.validate()) address1.save()
def address2 = new Addresses(firstLine:'A2', secondLine:'B2', thirdLine:'C2', luCountry:UnitedStates, zipCode:'12344', luState:Florida, city:'jag2')
if(address2.validate()) address2.save()


assertEquals 2, Addresses.list().size()
```

Comment: Its not working, when I am trying to put it like this, its giving an error : 
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: thlc.Addresses.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), isCase(java.lang.Object), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: I tried something like this :

Addresses a1 = new thlc.Addresses(firstLine:'A1', secondLine:'B', thirdLine:'C', luCountry:UnitedStates, zipCode:'12345', luState:Florida, city:'jag');
Addresses a2 = new thlc.Addresses(firstLine:'A2', secondLine:'B2', thirdLine:'C2', luCountry:UnitedStates, zipCode:'12344', luState:Florida, city:'jag2'); 
    
mockDomain(Addresses, [ a1, a2]);
a1.save();
a2.save();

But even this is not working, its giving the same problem as before.

Comment: You're adding logic to your test which in my opinion is a bad idea.  The problem with your proposed solution is that the objects may be added to the mock database and they may not be.  Your test will fail at the assert if you're production code is incorrect or for some reason your objects don't pass validation.  For this unit test we're not testing validity of objects but a controller method.  If you want to ensure valid objects you can use the .save(failOnError:true) which will fail at the point of saving and not at the assert.  My 2 cents.

Comment: I think the op is just playing around with tests for now. I tend to do the same to get a feel before I write real tests, or to make sure I really do have something persisted.

Comment: You were correct, the problem was I was not saving the instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing the model incorrectly.  In a unit test you should access the model via:

```
def model = controller.modelAndView.model
```

Then access whatever you want off of the model so in your instance it would be:

```
ac.list()
def model = ac.modelAndView.model
assertEquals(2, model.postInstanceList.size())
```